# Image inside flex-item rewrites "max-width: none" in Safari, iOS and Firefox

Tags: ios, html, css, safari

The a element gets its `height` from a script and the complete code works great on all devices and browsers except **iOS and Safari** (if small enough). There the image gets streched in `height`.

The goal was to get the image **centered** allways **with flex**. I use flex alot on that page, so I wanted to use it there as well.

http://codepen.io/notyetnamed/pen/gaboXK

EDIT: It´s not the max-height thats ignored, it´s the max-width that´s getting rewritten.

If I set `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` I get a similar view in chrome like it looks in safari.

EDIT2: The "bug" also appears in **firefox**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams to be not possible right now because of a bug in Safari, Firefox and some others.

So I removed the flex properties and added some normal style to keep the image centered in its container.

```
.box img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  right: -100%;
  top: -100%;
  bottom: -100%;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: none;
}
```

http://codepen.io/notyetnamed/pen/dYYYxP